# Show that $\lim \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ by definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Is my attempt correct?

*Proof*. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Take $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and let $n \geq N$. Then

$\begin{align}\displaystyle\left\lvert \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{n}} -1 \right\rvert 
&= \left\lvert \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}} -1 \right\rvert\\\\
&= \left\lvert \frac{\sqrt{n-1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \right\rvert\\\\
&= \left\lvert \frac{(\sqrt{n-1} - \sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n})} \right\rvert\\\\
&= \left\lvert \frac{(n-1)-n}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n})} \right\rvert\\\\
&= \left\lvert \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n})} \right\rvert\\\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n})}\\\\
& < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n})}= \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon\end{align}$

Comment: That's correct but you should also mentioned that somewhere that $n, N\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Very nice done...though you still need to add some explaining. But you have the bulk of the proof.

Comment: @Koro The definition we use explicitly states that $N \in \Bbb{N}$

Comment: Why can you take $N\gt \frac 1{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @Koro $N$ does not need to be in $\mathbb N$. Many expositions of real analysis do state the constraint that $N \in \mathbb N$ but it's not strictly necessary and can in fact make such convergence proofs more fiddly than they need to be. Reference Binmore's "Real Analysis" (1977, Cambridge) which is often overlooked.

Comment: @Divide1918 Archimedean Principle

Comment: You never specify what the variable tends to, and you should, here it's the "limit as $n \to \infty$". If the variable tends to something else than $\infty$, then the limit is not $1$.

Comment: @user3733558 you shouldn't have to specify that. its in the definition of a limit. the for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$ captures that idea precisely

Comment: If definition requires that $N \in \mathbb N$, then your proof (in order to be formally correct) must *assert* that $N \in \mathbb N$ in order to satisfy the definition.

Comment: @PrimeMover Completely in agreement with the $N \in \mathbb N$ agreement, I personally think that while there may be a reason for teaching it that way (which is my way of saying I don't want to enter that territory) we should be telling students early enough : just take the ceiling of whatever $N$ you should get and be done with it! Binmore's "Real Analysis"? Worth a read, let's see if I can get a copy from somewhere. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

One way to shorten this proof would be to use this [lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949866/prove-the-difference-of-roots-is-less-than-or-equal-to-the-root-of-the-differenc/3980793#3980793) which says that for $x,y\in[0,\infty)$, we have $$\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right|\leq\sqrt{\big||x|-|y|\big|}\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}$$

Then your proof would go $$\left|\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{1}\right|\leq\sqrt{\left|1-\frac{1}{n}-1\right|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}<\varepsilon$$
for $1/N<\varepsilon^2$ and $n\geq N$.

Don't forget to mention the Archimedean Property, but otherwise, nice job :)

Comment: The lemma is basically just the triangle inequality though

Comment: @Divide1918 fair point. I only mention it because you can apply it immediately and obtain the result instead of doing extra work for this specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

As the function values are smaller than $1$, we have to solve the inequation

$$1-\sqrt{1-\frac1n}<\epsilon$$ (we can assume $\epsilon\le1$ because for larger $\epsilon$ the inequation is always true), or

$$1-\epsilon<\sqrt{1-\frac1n},$$
$$(1-\epsilon)^2<1-\frac1n,$$
$$\frac1n<(2-\epsilon)\epsilon,$$
$$n>\frac1{(2-\epsilon)\epsilon}\ge\frac1{2\epsilon}$$
and this gives us a lower bound on $N$.

Comment: Last line should be $2-\epsilon<2$ thus $n\ge \frac 1{2\epsilon}$.

Comment: @zwim: thanks for the fix.